# Generating my own Eloquent model insert IDs - How to avoid PK Collisions?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Maybe this is a stupid question because I should defer PK increments to MySql itself, but I'm in a weird situation.

Basically to handle versioning and approvals in my system, I have `revision_batch` table which is a collection of things in a submission that a user wishes to insert or update to the database. It has columns like `batch_id`, the `user_id` of the submitter, and an `approved` value.

It also is parent to a collection of items in the `revisions` table. The revisions table has things like `table_name`,  `key`, `old_value`, and `new_value`.  I use this to store the changes someone wishes to make that may not be approved automatically.

When someone who doesn't have permission to, say, a "task" table, and they change the name of an task, a new `revision_batch` will be created, and a new `revision` will be created with `table_name`="tasks", `key`=[whatever the task's ID is], `old_value`="my old task name", `new_value`="my new task name".

When an approver approves of this batch, my code will rocket through the revisions in the batch and perform the update or inserts to the database.

My problem is when performing parent-child relationships within the same batch. If I'm creating a new `task` and want to assign a `task_item` to it, in the same batch, then I need to know what PK the `task` is getting so that I can give the `task_item` a "`task_id`".

If I'm handing the creation of a new `revision` for a `task`,  I might do something like a

```
select max(id)+1 as newId from tasks
```

to inject as the new id. But since I might already have a pending task insert revision with that ID or higher, I also check

```
select max(key) + 1 as newId 
from revisions 
inner join revision_batches on revisions.batch_id = revision_batches.id
where table_name='revisions' and approved = 'P'
```

for a higher id to assign. That way of I have ids 1-9 in a `tasks` table and 10-12 pending in the `revisions` table, any new direct insert using Laravel's Eloquent model class is overridden to check both tasks and revisions and will insert with id 13. This avoids collisions between actual cemented rows and possible revision rows. It also allows me to create a parent and many layers of children within a single batch because I determine their ID as I go along.

This is all works fine.

My problem is that if I have two `revisions` creations happening at the exact same time (like, within a millisecond) , they'll asynchronously both fetch the same next ID to use, both create revisions where key = the same number, and then only one will get through and the other fails on a PK collision.

My question is: is there a way to force this to be thread safe or to be done synchronously, to avoid two instances of the same controller method executing at the same time and both fetching the same ID to use? Can I lock a method down to a single instance at a time? If not, is there a better way I could be handling PK generation? The only reason I do this is to know beforehand the key to insert. But since custom code in the framework is handling PK generation and not the database, it's causing me this major issue. Happens sporadically, but only when I force the same method to execute maybe 4 times at the same time.

I know that I could avoid the majority of cases where I have many things being inserted at the exact same time, but that doesn't mean that randomly in the future that two users won't hit enter at the same time and recreate this issue.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this type of issues I use UUID 4, ([Universally unique identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29)), my case is a little bit different because I have a system in 74 different locations, but need to extract all the transaction records and integrate in a consolidation system, so my PKs needs to be unique across all servers to avoid collisions.

In laravel I use [this excelent package](https://github.com/webpatser/laravel-uuid) to generate the UUID

I hope this works for you.

Comment: I can't believe I never thought of something like this! I will try this tonight. I've never used UUIDs as PKs before so this will be interesting. This also obscures some of the IDs that I have visible as part of my routing URLs, which I like. Seeing ..../task/1/.... has always made me cringe. Thanks!

Comment: I went ahead and retroactively got unique IDs autogenerated on every insert operation for inheritors of my custom Eloquent model class. This works perfectly now. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Use Queues for saving your revisions.

Queues are synchronous, and hence the key collision will never occur.

Source: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queues

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into this. I've never heard of queues before in Laravel!